# Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,COERCIBLE) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'find_in_set'

Tags: mysql, collation

I get the following error:

> Illegal mix of collations
>   (latin1_swedish_ci,COERCIBLE) and
>   (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for
>   operation 'find_in_set'

This is the query I was trying to execute:

```
SELECT ID FROM xs_user_profiles WHERE ID='' AND FIND_IN_SET('1',site_structure);
```

I looked up the properties of this table and it has charset utf8 and collation utf8_general_ci.

This works well with all my sites so I am not sure what's going wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Troubleshooting "Illegal mix of collations" error in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029321/troubleshooting-illegal-mix-of-collations-error-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `mysqli`, issue this command right after connecting:

```
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");
```

This will set your connection encoding to `UTF8` (same as your table uses).

With plain `mysql`, use this:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8", $conn);
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8", $conn);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reaction but I use plain mysql.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your string literal ('1') is in a different collation due to different connection variables. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-literal.html)