# MySQL view - Illegal mix of collations

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064, collation

I'll be very clear: What's the solution for create views in MySQL without have the damned **Illegal mix of collations** error.

My SQL code is like this (it has some portuguese words), and my database default collation is **latin1_swedish_ci**:

```
CREATE VIEW v_veiculos AS
SELECT
    v.id,
    v.marca_id,
    v.modelo,
    v.placa,
    v.cor,
    CASE v.combustivel
        WHEN 'A' THEN 'Álcool'
        WHEN 'O' THEN 'Óleo Diesel'
        WHEN 'G' THEN 'Gasolina'
        ELSE 'Não Informado'
    END AS combustivel,
    marcas.marca,
    /*I think that the CONCAT and COALESCE below causes this error, when the next line the view works fine*/
    CONCAT(marca, ' ', v.modelo, ' - Placa: ', v.placa, ' - Combustível: ', COALESCE(v.combustivel, 'Não informado')) AS info_completa
FROM veiculos v
LEFT JOIN
    marcas on(marcas.id = v.marca_id);
```

I think that the error cause is because I'm using **coalesce** and/or **concat** as the full error's description tells me: **Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'coalesce'**

Comment: You can get answer in this stackoverflow question [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029321/how-to-solve-illegal-mix-of-collations-in-mysql

Comment: @Chella change the default database collate didn't work. I've already tried that.

Answer (score 6):

You may also use [`CAST()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-convert.html) to convert a string to a different character set. The syntax is:

```
CAST(character_string AS character_data_type CHARACTER SET charset_name)
```

eg:

```
      SELECT CAST(_latin1'test' AS CHAR CHARACTER SET utf8);
```

alternative : use `CONVERT(expr USING transcoding_name)`

Comment: Wow the code would be very big using this, I don't accept the MySQL don't simplify this task.

Comment: Hey diEcho, your solution solved partially my problem, In this case I'm doing like this: `CONVERT(_latin1' - Combustível: ' USING utf8)` but the results are like 'CombustÃ­vel' when the correct would be 'Combustível'. Do you know how can I correctly cast this?

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of old, but well
I had this same error, 
As far as I know the Views does not have a collation, the tables does. 
So, if you get the "illegal mix..." is because your view is linking (comparing, whatever) 2 tables with different collation
The thing is, if you create a table you can specify the collation, for instance

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `vwHotelCode_Terminal` (
`HOTELCODE` varchar(8)
,`TERMINALCODE` varchar(5)
,`DISTKM` varchar(6)
,`DISTMIN` varchar(3)
,`TERMINALNAME` varchar(50)
)ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci  ;
```

But if you don't, the default collation will be applied. So for me the defaul collation is `utf8_unicode_ci` so my tables will be created with this collation and I ended having some tables with `utf8_spanish_ci`  and the ones I did not specify with `utf8_unicode_ci`

If you are exporting from one server to another one and the default collation is different, you are probably going to get the "illegal mix" message.

if you have views, phpmyadmin likes to create the tables of all the views and then the views. The tables are created without the collation so it takes the default one. Then, many times, when the view is created uses different collations.

Answer (score 0):

That is actually a [bug](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=60101) in MySQL.

Maybe you can update to the latest version of MySQL?

Comment: My MySQL version is 5.5.27-log :/

Comment: I inspected the bug report. The error wasn't there in version 5.1.54, but in later ones. It seems to be fixed in `mysql-5.5.b60101`, but I am not sure which version of MySQL this is.

Answer (score 0):

After searching around for a while and taking information from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46353062/mysql-5-6-create-view-with-unicode-character-set), I found a *hack* that could be useful.

Simply check the default character set system **`default_character_set`** of your database with the below command:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "char%";
```

You'll see something like this:

`mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "char%";
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     | 
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       | <--
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+`

I just set the **`character_set_system`** which is nothing but default system character set. Copied the create code of the view and created a new view and that's all.

What happens here is the *new view* that you will create will use the *new default character set* that you defined for the system. Hence resolving the issue.

Just use below command to set the default character set

```
SET character_set_server = 'latin2';
```

This worked in my case.

**NOTE:** *Alternatively you can change the character set of that view. That would also do the trick but I wasn't able to find the solution so I used this hack.*

**REFERENCE:** Read more on [Illegal Collation Mix on MariaDB.](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/setting-character-sets-and-collations/#illegal-collation-mix)

**A CITATION FROM** [Illegal Collation Mix on MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/setting-character-sets-and-collations/#illegal-collation-mix):

> *If you encounter this issue, set the character set in the view to force it to the value you want.*

Read more about **Collation** and **Character Sets** [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/adding-collation.html).