# Illegal mix of collations in MySQL even with Collate and Binary Usage

Tags: mysql

Using this stack question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029321/how-to-solve-illegal-mix-of-collations-in-mysql), I tried to utilize collate and binary and am still getting the following error:

> Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Here is my MySQL query.  Is there anyway to solve this within the query?  I do not have access to alter the database or table, only to query it with SELECT.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
    Land.ListingAgentID,
    Land.StreetNumber,
    Land.PostalCode,
    Agent.FirstName,
    Agent.LastName,
    Agent.Email
FROM
    Land
        INNER JOIN
    Agent ON (Land.ListingAgentID = Agent.AgentID)
WHERE
    ListingID = `$MLNumber`;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can cast on the fly, which is slow. 
On the long view, you should use integers for joins.

```
INNER JOIN
Agent ON (Land.ListingAgentID = Agent.AgentID COLLATE utf8_general_ci )
```

Great answer and explanation here:
[Troubleshooting "Illegal mix of collations" error in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029321/how-to-solve-illegal-mix-of-collations-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use backticks `

Use quotes:

```
WHERE
    ListingID = '$MLNumber';
```

Comment: Bummer, I tried with and without quotes and still get the same problem, what do you think?

Comment: @RoccoTheTaco [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Thanks Neal, yes I'm working hard to covert everything...you provided some good links, thanks for the info!