# COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'

Tags: mysql

I am trying to fix a character encoding issue - previously we had the collation set for this column utf8_general_ci which caused issues because it is accent insensitive..

I'm trying to find all the entries in the database that could have been affected.

```
set names utf8;
select * from table1 t1 join table2 t2 on (t1.pid=t2.pid and t1.id != t2.id) collate utf8_general_ci;
```

However, this generates the error:

```
ERROR 1253 (42000): COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'
```

1. The database is now defined with `DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8`
2. The table  is defined with `CHARSET=utf8`
3. The "pid" column is defined with: `CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL`
4. The server version is Server version: 5.5.37-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 (Ubuntu)

Question: Why am I getting an error about latin1 when latin1 doesn't seem to be present anywhere in the table / schema definition?

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%collation%';
+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci   |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Please post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE table1` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE table2`.  What is your client connection charset?  Post also `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%'`

Comment: Oh you do have `set names utf8` so hopefully `character_set_client` will show `utf8`

Comment: This may be very helpful in this regard: https://scottlinux.com/2017/03/04/mysql-mariadb-set-character-set-and-collation-to-utf8/

Answer (score 54):

First, run this query:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%';
```

You have `character_set_server='latin1'` shown in your post ...

So, go into your `my.cnf` and add or uncomment these lines:

```
character-set-server = utf8
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
```

Restart the server.

Comment: Should that be `character-set-server` or `character_set_server`?

Comment: It should be character-set-server

Comment: character_set_server, MySQL 5.5

Comment: where to locate my.cnf file?

Comment: I'm using mysql 5.5.56 server

Comment: you can run ```mysql --help```

Comment: MariaDB  - my.cnf  location , i am unable to find location, kindly help

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04 I placed it in: `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` under `[mysqld]`

Comment: Thanks a lot for saving my life. Our mysql works normally for a week and cannot start up after reboot. I fixed it by add the 2 lines you mentioned. Why mysql works at the beginning and not start after reboot? It really drive me crazy.

Comment: I did what you suggested here and now after `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%';` I get `character_set_server = 'utf8'` but the error persists still. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: use `mysql --help | grep cnf` to find my.cnf file in your machine

Answer (score 8):

The same error is produced in MariaDB (10.1.36-MariaDB) by using the combination of parenthesis and the COLLATE statement. My SQL was different, the error was the same, I had:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE (field = 'STRING') COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Omitting the parenthesis was solving it for me.

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE field = 'STRING' COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Comment: If you can't omit the parenthesis use BINARY instead: `SELECT *
FROM table1
WHERE BINARY field = BINARY  'STRING';`

Answer (score 3):

In my case I created a database and gave the collation `'utf8_general_ci'` but the required collation was `'latin1'`. After changing my collation type to `latin1_bin` the error was gone.