# MySql VIEW created with charset latin1 all configs are set to utf8

Tags: mysql, encoding, collation

I'm trying to create a simple view but I'm getting error because the view is created with latin1 instead of utf8.

**The View** looks something like this:

```
create or replace view
  my_view
  as
    select * from my_table
  group by some_field
collate utf8_unicode_ci
;
```

**The error** I'm getting is:

```
COLLATION 'utf8_unicode_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'
```

**What I did**, was check multiple configuration options:

**Global**

```
show variables like "%char%";
character_set_client,utf8
character_set_connection,utf8
character_set_database,utf8
character_set_filesystem,binary
character_set_results,utf8
character_set_server,utf8
character_set_system,utf8
```

**The table** I'm using to create the view:

```
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_COLLATION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
where TABLE_NAME in ('my_table');
;
def,my_database,my_table,utf8_unicode_ci
```

**The Columns** of that table:

```
SELECT TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, COLLATION_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME in ('my_table');
def,my_database,my_table,id,null
def,my_database,my_table,active,null
def,my_database,my_table,title,utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: This below link might be helpful for you:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852239/collation-utf8-general-ci-is-not-valid-for-character-set-latin1

Comment: allready tried those config switches did not work out sadly

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE my_table`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in an MySQL database, where I had Umlauts/special charaters within a CASE like this (reduced sample):

```
CASE
 WHEN cfs.value = "ungeklärt" THEN "" -- the character 'ä' was an issue for me here
 ELSE cfs.value
END AS "Category"
```

The error popped up for me, when savin this statement as a view.
Can you check if it solves the issue for you, when you set the names accordingly **first**? In my case this was `latin1` instead of `utf8` due to an old legacy database.

```
set names latin1;
```

If I understood your case correclty it would be this for you instead:

```
set names utf8;
```