# The reason for working with migration is to create a table in mysql

Tags: laravel-5.8

php artisan migrate Error while executing

> Illuminate\Database\Query Exception:SQL STATE[42000]: Syntax error or
>   access  violation: 1253 COLLATION 'utf8_unicode_ci'  is not valid for
>   CHARACTER SET 'utf8 8mb4' (SQL: select * from
>   information_schema.tables where table_schema = warehousing sing and
>   table_name = migrations)

Comment: I hope this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852239 will give you some idea.

Comment: what's your question ??

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify following changes,

Go to **config > database.php**

```
'connections' => [
                  ....
                  'mysql' => [
                             ......
                             'charset' => 'utf8mb4', // Update here : 'utf8'
                             'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci', // Update here : utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Thank you my friend

Comment: Glade i can help you, please accept my answer as solved if this resolves the issue. :) Happy coding. If there is any further assistance needed let me know