# How to resolve the error : COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1' mysql verision 8.0.0 (docker,django,datagrip)

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, datagrip

I am trying to use datagrip for my database management. I can create a connection but when the data of the database I get this error:

```
[42000][1253] COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET
 'latin1'. COLLATION 'utf8_general_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'
```

I have looked only for solutions to this but non of them seem to work. A few of them involved changing the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file it showed the changes that should work but didn't have any effect.

***my.cnf:***

```
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
[client]
loose-default-character-set=utf8

[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8

[mysqld]
collation-server = utf8_unicode_ci
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
character-set-server = utf8
```

***the result:***

```
show variables like '%char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+


show variables like '%collation%'

+----------------------+-----------------+
| Variable_name        | Value           |
+----------------------+-----------------+
| collation_connection | utf8_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8_unicode_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [COLLATION 'utf8\_general\_ci' is not valid for CHARACTER SET 'latin1'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852239/collation-utf8-general-ci-is-not-valid-for-character-set-latin1)

Comment: i tried that one as well but it didnt resolve any thing :( (just tried it again and didnt work either)

Comment: which is MySQL server version? which driver version is selected in DataGrip? open data source properties. go to advanced tab and check parameters 'characterset' and 'characterSetResuts' are set to utf8.

Comment: what is collation of your target database?

Comment: @YuriWin characterSetResult = utf8 and i coudnt find characterset in advance options. the image that i use is mysql:8.0.0 image because that is the only one that works with the latest mysqlclient that i was able to find that works on windows i would like to use the latest version but i coudnt find a windows wheel file anywere for 2.0.1. i dont know what the collation is for my database at the moment (character_set_database = utf8 , collation_database = utf8_general_ci) the driver is 8.0.13

Answer (score 1):

It could be two issues here.

1. Table you're trying to get data from is created in different collation. So, `SHOW CREATE TABLE` show help to unveil if it is.
2. Your local machine and client are working in another collation. Setting `connectionCollation` on Advanced tab should help.
   [image: connectionCollation option]

Also, you can explicitly define collation by setting `SET NAMES utf8;` as startup script on data source' `Options` tab:
[image]