# Illegal mix of collations: latin1_swedish_ci and utf8_general_ci

Tags: mysql

The following is an error code that's coming up whenever I login to my website. Is there a relatively simple way to fix this? If yes, please help me understand how.

> Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'concat' SQL=SELECT * FROM hdyxf_mijoshop_customer WHERE LOWER(email) = 'changed@changed.com' AND (password = SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1(CONCAT(salt, SHA1('changed'))))) OR password = 'changed' OR password = 'changed' OR password = 'changed') AND status = '1' AND approved = '1'

Comment: See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029321/troubleshooting-illegal-mix-of-collations-error-in-mysql/3029483#3029483) for a proper answer.