# MySql self Join with array in

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named user, having these values:

```
 id    email 
  1    abc@abc.com
  2    test@abc.com
```

Now, I need a query like :

```
SELECT id, email from user where email in ('abc@abc.com`,`test@abc.com`,`xyz@aa.com`)
```

As **xyz@aa.com** doesn't exist in the table, I want the following results:

```
id    email 
1     abc@abc.com
2     test@abc.com
NULL  xyz@aa.com
```

Any idea how to do this in MySql?

Comment: So where is your `user_id`  and `email_id`?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Could you please explain more

Comment: I know of no way a SQL statement can be injected when it isn't taking in user input. If those emails are taken from user input they should be separated out. I'd be interested to know how this could be injected as it currently stands, @TimBiegeleisen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
SELECT user.id, user.email
FROM user
RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT 'abc@abc.com' AS email
        UNION SELECT 'test@abc.com'
        UNION SELECT 'xyz@aa.com'
    ) AS tmp
ON user.email = tmp.email;
```

Comment: I m getting this error - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029321/troubleshooting-illegal-mix-of-collations-error-in-mysql for solutions