# PHP & Illegal mix of collations in MySql dump file

Tags: php, mysql, collation

I wrote a PHP script to harvest some data that I want to enter into a database. This includes user's usernames that need to be entered, some users chose usernames with upside down text, i.e, 'uıɯpɐ'

I get a collation error when I use that username in a WHERE clause, is there a way for php to sanitize that before going into the database to avoid this?

```
#1267 - Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='
```

The way the script is set up I don't have much of a choice but to use the username in the where clause.

Comment: Can't you change the text codification of the database? Then it could be able to deal with it.

Comment: Another option I think of would be to not store the usernames, just their hash codifications, or the ASCII code, and whenever they log in, use a cookie to store and show them their usernames.

Comment: There's thousands of entries most are fine, is there a way to allow these type of characters, with the default character set with a SQL query?

Comment: @AlphaOmega are you able to insert into db but not use in where clause ?

Comment: Yes it appears it only encounters the error, when it's being used in a followup where clause AFTER an insert.

Comment: @AlphaOmega select that record & see the value for username stored correctly ?

Comment: No, it inserted as something like u??p?

Comment: There are some different solutions that might work: http://airbladesoftware.com/notes/fixing-mysql-illegal-mix-of-collations/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029321/troubleshooting-illegal-mix-of-collations-error-in-mysql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through/279279#279279

Answer (score 0):

`uıɯpɐ` comes from someone messing with your head.  It is characters scrounged from various UTF-8 charsets to make what *looks like* an upside down `admin`.  But note that he used a "dotless i" (a Turkish character) to sort of create the upside down `i`.

You should change any columns that need to have arbitrary characters from `latin1` to `utf8mb4`.  If you still have collation errors, we can discuss what else needs changing.  I can't be more specific without seeing the statement causing the error, `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the connection parameters.

More UTF-8 tips:  [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)