# How to get data from 3 different mysql tables with one query

Tags: php, mysql, email

My question is that I need to get a data (email) from different tables with one query. I have searched and I couldnt find enough information so I decided to ask here.

The idea is to send email to certain people from different departments and also send the email to everybody in all departments. 
 My code is below;

```
if ($_POST['recipient'] == 'parents'){$query = "SELECT `email`, `first_name` FROM `users` WHERE `allow_email` = 1 AND `active` = 1";}
        if ($_POST['recipient'] == 'teachers'){$query = "SELECT `email`, `name` FROM `teachers` WHERE `status` = 1";}
        if ($_POST['recipient'] == 'staff'){$query = "SELECT `email`, `name` FROM `staff`";}


        $result = $con->query($query);
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

            $mail = new PHPMailer();
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
            $mail->Host       = $site_settings['smtp_host']; // sets the SMTP server
            $mail->Port       = 26;                    // set the SMTP port
            $mail->Username   = $site_settings['smtp_username']; // SMTP account username
            $mail->Password   = $site_settings['smtp_password']; // SMTP account password
            $email->From      = $site_settings['school_email'];
            $email->FromName  = $site_settings['school_name'];
            $email->Subject   = 'Newsletter: '.$_POST['subject'];
            $email->Body      = $_POST['body'];
            $email->AddAddress( $row['email'] );

            $email->Send(); 
        }
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: How does your table schema look like?

Comment: Parents Table = user_id, username, password, first_name, last_name, email, telephone, email_code, active, password_recover, type, allow_email, profile.

Teachers = id, name, surname, telephone, email, status

Staff = id, name, surname, email, telephone, position.

I want to get the email data from all tables...

Comment: Use a [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html) between the three

Comment: I tried but UNION did not work or may be I couldnt use it properly. Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could create a view in MySQL database and aggregate data for one entity like this:

```
CREATE VIEW `all_user_emails` (email, name, type) AS 
SELECT `email`, `first_name`, 'user' FROM `users` WHERE `allow_email` = 1 AND `active` = 1
UNION
SELECT `email`, `name`, 'teacher' FROM `teachers` WHERE `status` = 1
UNION
SELECT `email`, `name`, 'staff' FROM 'staff'
```

Then you may query this view like a table like this

```
SELECT * FROM all_user_emails WHERE type = `staff`
```

Comment: I have tried your code but it did not produce any data.

Comment: @Vurkac Are there any errors? There is a typo here:  `WHERE status =` (should be `WHERE status = 1`), but aside from that, the code looks to be correct and seems to be what you want.

Comment: I have fixed that typo and I get this -> Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object.
Code is below:

$sql = "

CREATE VIEW `all_user_emails` (email, name, type) AS 
SELECT `email`, `first_name`, 'user' FROM `users` WHERE `allow_email` = 1 AND `active` = 1
UNION
SELECT `email`, `name`, 'teacher' FROM `teachers` WHERE `status` = 1
UNION
SELECT `email`, `name`, 'staff' FROM 'staff'

SELECT * FROM all_user_emails WHERE type = `staff`

";
$result = $con->query($sql);
 
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row['email'];
    }

Comment: @Vurkac You create the view in your database separately. Then you run the `SELECT` statement on your PHP page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UNION between the three tables to get one result set. The query would look like this:

```
SELECT `email`, `first_name`, 'user' FROM `users` WHERE `allow_email` = 1 AND `active` = 1
UNION
SELECT `email`, `name`, 'teacher' FROM `teachers` WHERE `status` = 1
UNION
SELECT `email`, `name`, 'staff' FROM `staff`
```

Your PHP code might look like this:

```
if ($_POST['recipient'] == 'parents'){$query = "SELECT `email`, `first_name` FROM `users` WHERE `allow_email` = 1 AND `active` = 1";}
elseif ($_POST['recipient'] == 'teachers'){$query = "SELECT `email`, `name` FROM `teachers` WHERE `status` = 1";}
elseif ($_POST['recipient'] == 'staff'){$query = "SELECT `email`, `name` FROM `staff`";}
elseif ($_POST['recipient'] == 'all')($query="SELECT `email`, `first_name`, 'user' FROM `users` WHERE `allow_email` = 1 AND `active` = 1 UNION SELECT `email`, `name`, 'teacher' FROM `teachers` WHERE `status` = 1 UNION SELECT `email`, `name`, 'staff' FROM `staff`")
```

The column names from the query would be the column names from the first SELECT of the UNION, so to access the value that would contain 'teacher', 'staff' or 'user' you would use `$row['user']` and if you wanted to use the person's name in your code you would use `$row['first_name']`, not `$row['name']`, but you could change that for consistency and clarity by starting out with:

```
SELECT `email`, `first_name` as name, 'user' as type FROM `users` ...
```

Comment: Thank you for reply. But I get tis error: Illegal mix of collations for operation 'UNION'. But when I remove the SELECT query for users, everything works fine. I think the reason is TEACHERS and STAFF tables have the same amount of column and the USERS table has more columns.

Is there anything to do to solve this issue?

Comment: That makes things complicated. I think perhaps this answer describes the problem better than I could: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029321/troubleshooting-illegal-mix-of-collations-error-in-mysql?rq=1