# SQL - Illegal mix of collations

Tags: mysql, collation

What I can do with this error: **`#1267`**

> Illegal mix of collations (utf8_czech_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Thanks:)

Comment: It's an illegal mix of collations. Most likely some of your tables are `utf8_czech_ci` but others are `utf8_general_ci`. Make sure they're the same.

Comment: pls providee the statement you issue returning this error msg

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029321/troubleshooting-illegal-mix-of-collations-error-in-mysql

Comment: I go to mariaDB and I set: `SET character_set_server = 'utf8'; SET collation_server = utf8_bin';`
it did not help ..

Comment: check columns that you are matching either in `on` or in `where` condition. if you are matching `col1=col2` then `col1` and `col2` must have same character set. (utf8_general_ci/utf8_czech_ci in your case)

Comment: Jimish Gamit - I do it and it not help.

Comment: @HonzaHála You did what? Make sure the collations were the same? Changed the collation in your query?

Comment: @h2ooooooo I go to Adjustments and I change Comparisons in all tables to utf8_czech_ci.

Comment: @HonzaHála Have you made sure that your VARCHAR's and columns in general are all utf8_czech_ci? FYI, we have no idea what program you're doing this with, so I don't know what "Adjustments" and/or "Comparisons" is in the program you're using.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%coll%`;` and the query that is giving the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Troubleshooting "Illegal mix of collations" error in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029321/troubleshooting-illegal-mix-of-collations-error-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

Execute the following and then run your original query again.

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
set collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci';
```

Comment: My sql query about a month ago still work ...Suddenly does not work, I do not understand.

Comment: I updated my ans with one more step. pls try again. setting collation_connection.

Comment: problem persists...,

Comment: No clue now. do you have the statement that I can use to recreate this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using variables, you can add the correct collation **next to your variable declaration**, i.e. instead of

```
SET @my_var = 'text';
```

declare the variables as

```
SET @my_var = 'text' COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Replace utf8_general_ci with the collation that is used in the table. More details on [Troubleshooting "Illegal mix of collations" error in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029321/troubleshooting-illegal-mix-of-collations-error-in-mysql)