# ResultSet.updateRow() produces "Illegal mix of collations (latin1_bin,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '<=>'"

Tags: java, mysql, resultset, collation

I have the following table with `name` being LATIN1 and the rest being UTF8.

```
CREATE TABLE `test_names` (
  `name` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL,
  `other_stuff_1` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `other_stuff_2` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

I encounter the following problem in Java:

I `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`.  Then I call `updateInt(2, 1)` and `updateRow()` on its ResultSet and get `Illegal mix of collations (latin1_bin,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '<=>'`.

**How can I make this work without changing the table’s / connection’s charset?**

Thanks a lot.

--- UPDATE ---

I use `SELECT name, other_stuff_1 FROM test_names LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;` and the connection string is `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + db + "?allowMultiQueries=true", user, password);`.

The exact stack trace is:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Illegal mix of collations (latin1_bin,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '<=>'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1086)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2156)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2441)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2366)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2350)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.UpdatableResultSet.updateRow(UpdatableResultSet.java:2405)
```

Comment: Please provide the entire `SELECT` statement, plus the other statements in the transaction.  Please provide the connection parameters used when connecting to MySQL.

Comment: Updated.  Thank you for your help, @RickJames.

Comment: Change `SELECT` statement to `SELECT name, other_stuff_1 FROM test_names LIMIT 1 ORDER BY name COLLATE latin1_bin FOR UPDATE`. I didn't test the statement, it required MySQL 5.7 or higher version.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, @beckyang. I tried `ORDER BY name COLLATE latin1_bin LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE` (ORDER BY goes in front of LIMIT), but unfortunately still receive `java.sql.SQLException: Illegal mix of collations (latin1_bin,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '<=>'`.

Comment: Probably a bug in Connector/J—you appear to be using v5.1.29, whereas the current GA release is v5.1.38.  Are you able to try with the latest version?

Comment: you may take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21061305/2368696)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my side, I can give you some suggestions

1. First update your Connector/J latest version.
2. Run this query

> ```
> SET NAMES='utf8'
> ```

3. Add `&characterEncoding=UTF-8` onto your JDBC connect string. Hope you have done it already.
4. Use `convert() for insert or update` and `cast() for select` query. For more details http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-convert.html
5. For "**Illegal mix of collations"** related issue, you can follow up [Troubleshooting "Illegal mix of collations" error in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029321/troubleshooting-illegal-mix-of-collations-error-in-mysql/21061305#21061305)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to select from a table which has different charsets on different columns.

You have to convert the columns that have different charsets in the query to the proper charset using `CONVERT()`.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-convert.html

In your case, you should modify your query to:

```
SELECT CONVERT(name USING latin1), other_stuff_1 FROM test_names LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Using `CONVERT` does not work, as it makes the `ResultSet` not updatable; I cannot update `other_stuff_1` any longer. The error message reads
`com.mysql.jdbc.NotUpdatable: Result Set not updatable (references computed values or doesn't reference any columns or tables).This result set must come from a statement that was created with a result set type of ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE, the query must select only one table, can not use functions and must select all primary keys from that table. See the JDBC 2.1 API Specification, section 5.6 for more details.`

Comment: The `ResultSet` is created with `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` and `ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE`.  The error appears due to converting.

But this is definitely the right approach.  I somehow need to tell Java that the PK in this DB is LATIN1.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you can't use updatable resultset in this case when the encoding in the table is not uniform (for example the primary key is in latin1 but the other columns are in utf8).

As Andras pointed out, you can convert the encoding on the sql side but then you won't be able to update the resultset.

Why don't you simply update the table with executeUpdate(...)? You can narrow down the target line(s) with a simple select then iterate over the resulting primary key list and call executeUpdate.

For me that is working for mixed encoded columns. Just an example:

```
    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT name other_stuff_1 FROM test_names");
    List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
    while(rs.next()) {
        keys.add(rs.getString(1));
    }
    rs.close();
    for(String key : keys) {
        st.executeUpdate("update test_names set other_stuff_1='"+key.length()+"', other_stuff_2='" + key.toUpperCase() + "' where name='" + key + "'");
    }
    conn.commit();
```