# #1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_slovak_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Tags: mysql, collation

I woud like to make join between tables in different collations. But it throws me an error #1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_slovak_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

```
SELECT `orders`.* from `orders`
JOIN `users` ON `orders`.`users_id` = `users`.`id`
JOIN `acl_users` ON `acl_users`.`email` = `users`.`email` 
AND `acl_users`.`id` != `users`.`id`
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Check the collations in acl_users and users tables and align them to each other.

Comment: I founded out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029321/troubleshooting-illegal-mix-of-collations-error-in-mysql?rq=1

Comment: What parameters are you using when connecting?  What collation, if any, is mentioned in my.cnf?  What is the charset of the column?