# mysql type conversion within operator if

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation

Test query:

```
select if(true,get_paper_real_amount(11),'абвгд');
```

where `get_paper_real_amount(int(11))` is stored function returning `int(11)` and `'абвгд'` as cp1251 string.

On mysql 5.0 and 5.1 everything works charming.
On mysql 5.5 and 5.6 (doesn't tested on other versions) there are issue, getting error:

`Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,COERCIBLE) and (cp1251_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operator if`

Manual [says](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

```
IF(expr1,expr2,expr3)
....
If expr2 or expr3 produce a string, the result is a string.
```

Obviously `get_paper_real_amount(11)` result converted to char using `latin1` character set and `latin1_swedish_ci` collation, whereas `show variables like '%character%'` reports:

```
character_set_client    cp1251
character_set_connection    cp1251
character_set_database  cp1251
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   cp1251
character_set_server    cp1251
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/local/mysql/share/charsets/
```

Furthermore, I compiled both 5.5 and 5.6 with

```
cmake . -DDEFAULT_CHARSET=cp1251 -DDEFAULT_COLLATION=cp1251_general_ci
```

and still has no success.

I have app developed in the 5.0 era, now gonna update to modern mysql version, but that issue making me to update alot of code... Is there any walkaround?

Comment: think this is interesting reading for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029321/troubleshooting-illegal-mix-of-collations-error-in-mysql

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE FUNCTION get_paper_real_amount` on 5.5 or 5.6.

Comment: Were you using a version of 5.1 before 5.1.21?

Comment: mysql support claim it is not a bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89440