# Collation Error on UPDATE statement using a defined function

Tags: mysql, collation

As you will see from my code, I've already specified the collation of my created table and the return of my function, yet I'm still getting the error message. Why is that ?

I'm getting the following error when applying my query in PHPmyAdmin-MYSQL:
SQL query:
UPDATE tb SET balance  = (SELECT fnaccount_getbalance(acguid COLLATE utf8_general_ci,accur COLLATE  utf8_general_ci,@stdate,@endate))
Error:

## 1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Here is my Query:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tb (id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                           acguid char(38),
                           accur char(38),
                           account varchar(255),
                           debitsyp float,
                           creditsyp float,
                           balance float,
                           currency varchar(255))
CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
SET @stdate = '2011-01-01';
SET @endate = CURDATE();

INSERT INTO tb (acguid,accur,account,debitsyp,creditsyp,balance,currency)
SELECT ac.guid,ac.currencyguid,CONCAT(ac.code,'-',ac.name) AS account,0,0,0,my.code
FROM ac000 ac INNER JOIN my000 my ON ac.currencyguid = my.guid
WHERE ac.guid IN (SELECT accountguid FROM en000);

UPDATE tb SET debitsyp = (SELECT SUM(debit) FROM en000 WHERE accountguid = acguid);
UPDATE tb SET creditsyp = (SELECT SUM(credit) FROM en000 WHERE accountguid = acguid);

UPDATE tb SET balance  = (SELECT fnaccount_getbalance(acguid,accur,@stdate,@endate));

SELECT * FROM tb;
```

And here is the code for my function fnaccount_getbalance:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE acbal float;
    SET acbal = (SELECT IFNULL(SUM((CASE
                                    WHEN currencyguid = accur THEN debit / currencyval
                                    ELSE debit / fngetcurval(accur,endate)
                                    END) - 
                                (CASE
                                    WHEN currencyguid = accur THEN credit / currencyval
                                    ELSE credit / fngetcurval(accur,endate)
                                END)),0) as balance
                FROM en000 WHERE accountguid = acguid
                AND endate BETWEEN stdate AND endate);
    
    RETURN (acbal COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci);
END
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Troubleshooting "Illegal mix of collations" error in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029321/troubleshooting-illegal-mix-of-collations-error-in-mysql)

Comment: As you can see from my code, I've already specified the collation of my created table and the return of my function, yet I'm still getting the error message. Why is that ?

Comment: Balance field and actbal variables are numbers, so collation cannot be a problem, so using collations to turn them into strings is pointless. The error must come from within the function - probably when you do the select from the other table. The error message shows explicit string colkation conversion, while the code does not have this conversion when you pass the parameters. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the matter by changing the DATABASE collation to utf8_unicode_ci

Previously it was utf8_general_ci

Then I Dropped and recreated all the functions I had in a new SQL query

Originally I set the database collation to utf8_general_ci based on an advice from another website, is it bad to set DATABASE collation to unicode instead of general ?

Comment: `utf8_general_ci` is a simplistic collation.  Better is `utf8_unicode_ci`, which corresponds to the rather old Unicode 4.0 standard.  Then came the 5.20 standard and `utf8_unicode_520_ci`.  When you get to MySQL 8.0, there is an even better collation.

Comment: On the other hand, you are not likely to notice any difference in those collations.