# replace function not working with bind_param

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, slim

I am trying to save the binary of UUID as primary key in a table.

I am using the `UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID(),"-",""))` to convert the UUID to binary after removing the dashes from it. This works perfect in SQL query executed directly on phpMyAdmin. But in a SLIM php prepared statement it gives me the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean.

```
$stmt = $this->conn->prepare("INSERT INTO profile(profile_id, profile_firstname, profile_lastname) values (UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID(),'-','')),?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $profile_firstname,$profile_lastname);
$stmt->execute();
```

Note that if i write any static value (i.e. `'123'`) instead of `UNHEX(REPLACE(UUID(),'-',''))` error is gone.

Comment: Execute `SELECT REPLACE(UUID(),'-','')`. Think what will return its UNHEX()... char-by-char...

Comment: @Akina No, I want to store it as binary this is why I use UNHEX. The query has no errors, I tried it on phpMyAdmin, but binding error exists.

Comment: @Dharman Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE), (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE),
  (utf8_unicode_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation 'replace'

Comment: You should have been using utf8mb4. To solve it you can just cast the value to the collation you need.

Comment: [Troubleshooting “Illegal mix of collations” error in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029321/troubleshooting-illegal-mix-of-collations-error-in-mysql)

Comment: @Dharman can you show an example?