# Illegal mix of collations in query results why not change it all into utf8_general_ci

Tags: mysql, collation

We got this error message from MYSQL: Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) for instance on search results.

```
collation_connection = utf8_general_ci
collation_database = latin1_swedish_ci
collation_server = latin1_swedish_ci
collation tables = a mix of latin1_swedish_ci and utf8_general_ci
collation columns = a mix of latin1_swedish_ci and utf8_general_ci
collation fields = a mix of latin1_swedish_ci and utf8_general_ci
```

So my suggestion is to change it all into utf8_general_ci

I tested columns + fields:

```
ü  Ü ï € á à é É  [into utf8] ü  Ü ï € á à é É, result seems ok. Every character is correct shown.
```

In our firm there is nobody with enough understanding of this.
Is there any reason why I should not do this action?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Troubleshooting "Illegal mix of collations" error in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029321/troubleshooting-illegal-mix-of-collations-error-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

It would be even better to move to the utf8mb4 collations instead of utf8.

Yes, it is probably wise to move almost everything to utf8mb4.

If you have MySQL 5.5 or 5.6, there could be issues with utf8mb4.  However, there are workarounds.

There are a few ways of converting tables, but only one way will be correct.  And which way is "correct" depends on whether the data in the table is messed up.  `SELECT HEX(col) ...` will give `FCDCEF80E1E0E9C9` for `üÜï€áàéÉ` if the `CHARACTER SET` (that is, the "encoding") is latin1.  For utf8 or utf8mb4, the hex will be `C3BCC39CC3AFE282ACC3A1C3A0C3A9C389`.

See `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'chara%';` -- some of those should not be changed.  The ones to focus on are the three set by `SET NAMES utf8mb4;`.  (Do the `SHOW` again, to see which ones changed.  Then another `SET` to get them back.)

As for which `COLLATION` to go with, `..._general_ci` is the least interesting.  However, until you get into the details of comparisons or ordering for various languages, the collation won't matter much.

The charset and collation of a database are the *defaults* for newly created tables.  Instead of worrying about that, get in the habit of being explicit on `CREATE TABLE`.  The charset and collation of a table are the *defaults* for newly columns in the table.

Then there is the charset and collation on the *connection*.  This is important because it declares the encoding (charset) of the byte in the client.  The collation of the connection may affect the question you posed.  (Sorry, but there was a lot of groundwork to lay before getting to your Question.)  So make the collation consistent with your databases and tables.