# Procedure in mysqldb fails Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'like'

Tags: mysql, collation

I am running the procedure in mysql but it fails due to the below error

> ERROR 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation 'like'

```
mysql> show PROCEDURE STATUS where name like 'PRE_PROCESSING';

+-----------------+----------------+-----------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| Db | Name | Type | Definer | Modified | Created | Security_type | Comment | character_set_client | collation_connection | Database Collation |
+-----------------+----------------+-----------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
| main_model | PRE_PROCESSING | PROCEDURE | main_model@% | 2020-09-18 20:30:18 | 2020-09-18 20:30:18 | DEFINER | | utf8mb4 | utf8mb4_general_ci | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+-----------------+----------------+-----------+-------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+---------+----------------------+----------------------+--------------------+
    
mysql> show TABLE STATUS where name like 'Customer'; +-----------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+ | Name      | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows  | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time | Check_time | Collation          | Checksum | Create_options | Comment | +-----------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+ | Customer | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    | 14174 |            338 |     4800512 |               0 |      3735552 |   2097152 |           NULL | 2020-09-18 20:30:17 | NULL        | NULL       | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |     NULL |                |         | +-----------+--------+---------+------------+-------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+-------------+------------+--------------------+----------+----------------+---------+ 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
    
show variables like "%collation%";
+----------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+----------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_database | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
| collation_server | utf8mb4_unicode_ci |
+----------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: I'd use explicit collation specifying. Show the statement which causes the problem.

Comment: please show the output of `show create procedure PRE_PROCESSING \G` and `show create table Customer \G` and the request you are making that causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP PROCEDURE ...
SET NAMES ...
CREATE PROCEDURE ...
```

That is, alter the procedure to be using the desired charset and `COLLATION`.

If this fails, then see [Troubleshooting "Illegal mix of collations" error in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029321/troubleshooting-illegal-mix-of-collations-error-in-mysql) , which was previously linked as a "duplicate".