# MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; in stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am trying to make a stored procedure in phpmyadmin.
I do this in PHP MyAdmin for instance

```
 UPDATE financeplusacct SET bal = bal - 5000 WHERE accNum = 00343297587;
UPDATE financeplusacct SET bal = bal + 5000 WHERE accNum = 00343995977
```

It posts fine without worries then i try to make it a stored procedure so my Javascript REST api can call it without hassle, Looks like this

```
UPDATE financeplusacct SET bal = bal - amount WHERE accNum = accNum1;
UPDATE financeplusacct SET bal = bal + amount WHERE accNum = accNum2;
```

And i am getting this as an Error

```
One or more errors have occurred while processing your request:
The following query has failed: "CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `ExecDebitCredit`(IN `accNum1` VARCHAR(150), IN `accNum2` VARCHAR(150), IN `amount` DECIMAL(18,2)) NOT DETERMINISTIC CONTAINS SQL SQL SECURITY DEFINER UPDATE financeplusacct SET bal = bal - amount WHERE accNum = accNum1; UPDATE financeplusacct SET bal = bal + amount WHERE accNum = accNum2;"

MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE financeplusacct SET bal = bal + amount WHERE accNum = accNum2' at line 2
```

Please is there something i am not getting rightly?

Comment: Show complete SP code. Do you remember about DELIMITER reassign?

Comment: I did not use a SP code. I used routines instead.

Comment: You need to wrap your code - the two `UPDATE` calls - with `BEGIN` ... `END`.

Comment: @MarcinJ, That part worked , now i am getting this as Error  The following query has failed: "SET @p0='00343995977'; SET @p1='00343297587'; SET @p2='3000'; CALL `ExecDebitCredit`(@p0, @p1, @p2); "

MySQL said: #1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

When I try to execute a test

Comment: For collation mix; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029321/troubleshooting-illegal-mix-of-collations-error-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks guys, changing to utf8mb4_general_ci worked thanks everyone

Comment: *I did not use a SP code. I used routines instead.* The term "routine" in MySQL means "stored procedure or function".