# Missing illegal Collation issues after upgrading mysql5.7 to mysql8.0.3*

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, mysql-8.0, mysqlupgrade

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1267 Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb3_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '=', query was:  SELECT` mobile_users`.* FROM` mobile_users `WHERE (first_name = 'John') AND (last_name = 'Rodríguez')`

Getting above error when running a select query in php, Last_name is having special character so this issue occurs. but this was working fine in mysql5.7 and now after upgrade to mysql8.0 getting above exception.

How to fix this one without modifying existing production data's in db. My DB structure is (SaaS) Client based dbs. So have many db's which is created using mysql5.7.

Comment: you try by explicitly specifying the collation in your select query

Comment: Your data to be compared have different CHARACTER SET - you cannot compare them directly. Convert your literals to the charset which is assigned to the column (use CONVERT() function or specify it in the literal prefix). Then specify correct collation if needed. Something like `.. WHERE (first_name = _utf8mb3'John' COLLATE utf8mb3_general_ci) ..`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Troubleshooting "Illegal mix of collations" error in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029321/troubleshooting-illegal-mix-of-collations-error-in-mysql)